# how to prevent clipping leaves when done through ParticleSystem?

Tags: particles

I am reproducing a crawling ivy vine on a tree. So I have done the following:

1. create a cylinder with lots of loop cuts (for the creeping vine). Select some vertices, and create a Vertex group and assign.
2. Create an Image plane with a PNG file of an ivy leaf.
3. Create a Particle system on the Cylinder object, and do Hair, and Render the Instance object and select the Image plane object. Select the Vertex group as the Density. Increase emission number.

However, now that I have the leaves, they are clipping into the tree trunk, and into each other. Is there any way to minimize this clipping?

Thanks.
[image]

Comment: This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but instancing things via a hair particle system has been pretty much rendered obsolete by geometry nodes. A simple "distribute points on faces" node set to _poisson disc_ will allow you to set a minimum distance between instances, and further adding to the node tree will allow you to more easily customize the scale. rotation and position of the instances as well.

Comment: Are the leaves on the branches and the branches on the trunk? And the problem is that the leaves intersect with the trunk, right? I don't know how to solve this easily without moving the branches or cutting the leaves. But I think you will have the same problem with Geometry Nodes and this won't help you.

Comment: You would need collision detection for the leaves and the trunk. May try a cloth simulation? Not sure if this is a good idea and if it works with particles or geometry nodes.

Comment: I was able to rotate the leaf objects randomly and phase them, so it looks somewhat plausible. I have not even started learning about Geometry Nodes.